# Why does my Regex (in php) not work?

Tags: php, regex

$data is a HTML text which contains a lot of anchor texts (links)

```
$regex = '/\b<a/i';
$data = '<a href="#">test</a> <a href="#">test 2</a>';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
```

returns nothing, but $data has two `<a`'s.

```
$regex = '/\b</i';
```

returns lots of '<' like expected

```
$regex = '/\ba/i';
```

returns lots of 'a' like expected, but

```
$regex = '/\b<a/i';
```

returns nothing.

Why is that?

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: We need to see all your code.  Also, using regexes for parsing HTML is a recipe for sorrow.

Comment: I think a [Short, Self-Contained, Compileable Example](http://sscce.org) would help here.

Comment: What Exactly do you want to match??... the `anchor` tags or the `text` between tags??...

Answer (score 3):

Besides not using a [DOM parser](http://php.net/domdocument), using `\b` is the problem here, because it basically matches the transition between a "word-like" character and something that's not, i.e.

```
(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W)
```

In this case, only if `<` is preceded by a letter will `\b` match, e.g.:

```
foo<a
```

Perhaps a better expression would be this:

```
'/(?<=\s|>)<a/i'
```

Or, even just this:

```
'/<a/i'
```

Comment: Something like that I thought also. But when I take out the \b changes nothing: $regex = '/<a/i'; also does not return anything

Comment: @user3765831 It certainly does change something; see [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/e1kol8).

Comment: Sure that's what I just answered in my answer below before you added the edit, though I noticed He mentioned in his first comment that event `/<a/i` returned nothing for him...Strange though

Comment: I have it reproduced: [LINK](http://codepad.viper-7.com/w12RNs) with '<a' --> no HTML output ---- [LINK](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GuG7dz) with only '<' HTML output 4 x '<'

Comment: @user3765831 Check the frame source; you forgot to use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: But where to use? See above.

Comment: @Daniel Look, when you're testing code you should either run it from the console (using cli) or always check the page source rather than the rendered output.

Comment: ok. So the source code is right. But what I need is the rendered output.

Comment: @Daniel Well, you could do `echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($matches, true));`.

Answer (score 2):

If you Want To match only the `<a`....

This should be enough.
`/<a/i`

```
$data = "<a>Link 1</a> <a>Link 2</a> <a>Link 3</a>";
$regex =  '/<a/i'; //also will match <A in <A>Text</A>
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches); //

/*
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '<a' (length=2)
      1 => string '<a' (length=2)
      2 => string '<a' (length=2)

*/
```

Comment: My [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CXW2z3) produces different output. Why?

Comment: can you copy and paste my code just the way it is, and test run?

Comment: Yes. I've done it [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/P0yVlx) --> Same Result. No HTML Output

Comment: You code's Working perfectly see here:: http://ideone.com/uxlkAu

Comment: This is a little confusing for me. Your ideone says what I would expect. [Codepad-viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/P0yVlx) (and unfortunately my server also) does not. There must be an explanation.

Comment: what is you try a simple code like: `$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5)` and `var_dump($arr)` try to run it in ur server first

Answer (score 0):

> $regex = '/\b<a/i'; returns nothing. Why is that?

`\b` is called a **word boundary**. It matches when one side is a "word character) (letters, digit or underscore), and when the other side is not a word character.

When you are trying to match `<a` in `text <a...`, there is no word boundary to the left of the `<`:

- to the left is the `<` (not a word character)
- to the right is a space (not a word character).

**Reference:**

- [Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: ok. I have also tried without the \b (see above) but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you tell me what problem persists? With `$regex="~<a~";` you will match any `<a`, is that what you want or am I missing something?

Comment: I have it reproduced: [with '<a'](http://codepad.viper-7.com/w12RNs)  --> no HTML output ---- [with only '<'](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GuG7dz) -->  HTML output 4 x '<'

Comment: It's totally working. :) The html output pane doesn't know what to do with the `<a` to display, that's normal. Add htmlentities to the output and you can see it: [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gse3U6) Let me know if that makes sense. :)